# threejs, adding points to scene and not seeing them

Tags: javascript, events, three.js, mouse, render

Hello I have one doubt:

I have studied:

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/PointsMaterial

And I have adapted the example to work with my existing code.

The aim is to render points on top of the model which we have loaded on click position.

Here we have the code, the important part is onDocumentMouseDown(), the file, logic.js:

```
if (!Detector.webgl) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

// global variables for this scripts
let OriginalImg,
    SegmentImg;

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mousePressed = false;
var clickCount = 0;


init();
animate();


// initilize the page
function init() {
    let filename = "models/nrrd/columna01.nrrd"; // change your nrrd file
    let idDiv = 'original';
    OriginalImg = new InitCanvas(idDiv, filename);
    OriginalImg.init();
    console.log(OriginalImg);

    filename = "models/nrrd/columnasegmentado01.nrrd"; // change your nrrd file
    idDiv = 'segment';
    SegmentImg = new InitCanvas(idDiv, filename);
    SegmentImg.init();
}

let originalCanvas = document.getElementById('original');
originalCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
originalCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);


function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    mousePressed = true;

    clickCount++;

    mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - OriginalImg.renderer.domElement.offsetLeft ) / OriginalImg.renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -( ( event.clientY - OriginalImg.renderer.domElement.offsetTop ) / OriginalImg.renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1

    console.log('Mouse x position is: ', mouse.x, 'the click number was: ', clickCount);
    console.log('Mouse Y position is: ', mouse.y);

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse.clone(), OriginalImg.camera);
    var objects = raycaster.intersectObjects(OriginalImg.scene.children);

    var pointGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();


    var position = new THREE.Vector3();
    position.x = objects[0].point.x;
    position.y = objects[0].point.y;
    position.z = objects[0].point.z;

    pointGeometry.vertices.push(position);


    var pointMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({color: 0x888888});

    var point = new THREE.Points(pointGeometry, pointMaterial);

    OriginalImg.scene.add(point);

    console.log(objects);
}

function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {
    mousePressed = false
}


function animate() {


    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    OriginalImg.animate();
    SegmentImg.animate();


}
```

And we do add the points to the scene, but in fact they do not render, they do not show, and I wonder why?:

[image]

As you could see in the image we see that the raycaster intercepts those new created points, however the do not get drawn.

I wonder if they are too small, or just the color hides them with the background.

***Could you help me please?.***

Additional code:

```
// this class handles the load and the canva for a nrrd
// Using programming based on prototype: https://javascript.info/class
// This class should be improved:
//   - Canvas Width and height

InitCanvas = function (IdDiv, Filename) {


    this.IdDiv = IdDiv;
    this.Filename = Filename
}

InitCanvas.prototype = {

    constructor: InitCanvas,

    init: function () {

        this.container = document.getElementById(this.IdDiv);

        // this should be changed.
        debugger;
        this.container.innerHeight = 600;
        this.container.innerWidth = 800;

        //These statenments should be changed to improve the image position
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, this.container.innerWidth / this.container.innerHeight, 0.01, 1e10);
        this.camera.position.z = 300;

        let scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.add(this.camera);

        // light

        let dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        dirLight.position.set(200, 200, 1000).normalize();

        this.camera.add(dirLight);
        this.camera.add(dirLight.target);


        // read file

        let loader = new THREE.NRRDLoader();
        loader.load(this.Filename, function (volume) {

            //z plane
            let sliceZ = volume.extractSlice('z', Math.floor(volume.RASDimensions[2] / 4));

            debugger;
            this.container.innerWidth = sliceZ.iLength;
            this.container.innerHeight = sliceZ.jLength;

            sliceZ.mesh.material.color.setRGB(0,1,1);


            console.log('Our slice is: ', sliceZ);

            scene.add(sliceZ.mesh);
        }.bind(this));


        this.scene = scene;

        // renderer

        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(this.container.devicePixelRatio);
        debugger;
        this.renderer.setSize(this.container.innerWidth, this.container.innerHeight);

        // add canvas in container
        this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    },

    animate: function () {

        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }

}
```

I wonder about the point size because if we see this example they are made with 0.05 of size:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_raycasting_points.html

And in the example we see the camera being quite far away from the points being generated and they are visible:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_raycasting_points.html

**What do you think?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `THREE.BufferGeometry()` with [`.setDrawRange()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry.setDrawRange):

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(1, 5, 5);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(3, 32, 24), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  wireframe: true,
  color: "red"
}));
scene.add(mesh);

var idx = 0;
var maxIdx = 10;

var points = [];
for (let i = 0; i < maxIdx; i++) {
  points.push(new THREE.Vector3());
}
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
geometry.setDrawRange(0, idx);

var points = new THREE.Points(geometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: 0.125,
  color: "yellow"
}));
scene.add(points);

window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);
window.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown, false);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersects = [];

function onMouseMove(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(mesh);
  if (intersects.length === 0) return;

  if (idx == maxIdx) return;

  let p = intersects[0].point;
  geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ(idx, p.x, p.y, p.z);
  geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
  idx++;
  geometry.setDrawRange(0, idx);
}

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/91/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```